# Change the order of before hooks in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a controller spec like this :

```
describe "#create" do
  before { post 'create', params }
  context "when the artist is valid" do
    before { allow(artist).to receive(:save).and_return(true) }
    it { expect(page).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    it { expect(notifier).to have_received(:notify) }
  end
end
```

This is a simple spec but It doesn't work because the describe's before block is executed before the context's before block. So, the result of `artist.save` is not stubed when the create action is called.

It tried to do this :

```
describe "first describe" do
  before { puts 2 }
  describe "second describe" do
    before { puts 1 }
    it "simple spec" do
      expect(1).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

I see the "2" before the "1". I'm not sure but I think it was working with previous versions.

I know, I can do this :

```
describe "#create" do
  context "when the artist is valid" do
    before { allow(artist).to receive(:save).and_return(true) }
    it "redirect to the root path" do
      post 'create', params
      expect(page).to redirect_to(root_path)
    end

    it "do notifications" do
      post :create, params
      expect(notifier).to have_received(:notify)
    end
  end
end
```

But I think it's less clean.

I found, on this page, http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks#before-instance_method than the order should be this :

```
before(:suite) # declared in RSpec.configure
before(:all)   # declared in RSpec.configure
before(:all)   # declared in a parent group
before(:all)   # declared in the current group
before(:each)  # declared in RSpec.configure
before(:each)  # declared in a parent group
before(:each)  # declared in the current group
```

It's not the case on this example.

I'm not sure but I think it was working with older versions of rspec.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against you changing the order of hooks in rspec. That will make your app non-standard and Rails is build on standards and having things work as expected.

Everything you're describing it "as designed". Outer before blocks are always called before inner blocks.

Your example that you feel is "less clean" is the standard way to do controller specs. I actually encourage you to do it this way so that it is more maintainable/readable. It does not look unclean to me at all.

That said, there are some options:

1. You can use a method. I have more than once had a method that was `do_post` or something similar
2. You can use a `let` block which is initialized lazily. I would find it unlcean if it relied  on other before blocks running first, but it's an option.
3. You can define `subject`. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/subject/explicit-subject

Comment: I agree. I already tried some of this solutions but I did not try to place the post call in the before block. I will create a subject like this `subject(:do_post) { post 'create', args } ` and call the do_post function in the context's before block.

Comment: I recommend using `let` for this, not `subject`. Then call it `:post_response`. So: `let(:post_response) { post 'create', args }`